# React native compress a video file

Tags: react-native

I'm recording a video using [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) after stop the recording I want to compress the video and upload to a server. I'm using [react-native-zip-archive](https://github.com/mockingbot/react-native-zip-archive) but the compressed file I get is always empty. Any idea of how to compress the file properly?

```
this.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
          .then((data) => {
        return zip(sourcePath, targetPath)
        .then((path) => {
            console.log(`zip completed at ${path}`);
            return RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST','https://server/upload', {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                }, [
                    { name : 'video-comperss', filename : 'video-comperss', type:'video/quicktime', data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(path)},
                ])
                .then((res) => {
                    if (res.respInfo.status === 200) {
                        console.log('done');
                    }
                    return RNFS.unlink(targetPath)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('file deleted');
                    });
                });
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: 1. What have you tried to debug this? For example, does your code work if you don't zip prior to uploading? 2. Zipping video files won't save you all that much space (if at all considering the format). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It works if I don't zip the file. I'm trying to upload the file to the server and save as much as space as possible during the upload but still keeping good quality, can you think anything to achieve that?

Comment: If that's your goal, then zip is definitely the wrong approach. It'll add a lot of extra CPU usage on mobile for little to zero gain because of the video format. If you need to do this, then I recommend figuring out your requirements first. For ex: do you *need* to keep the original file? If so, then your options are very limited. It's been years since I delved into this topic, but you'll want to read up on the different compression methods like 7z, lzma, gzip (0-9?), etc. I've never attempted it on mobile, but I would image that most won't perform very well.

Comment: Second, I recommend reading up on the differences between the different video file formats; especially lossless vs lossy. For video (& audio & image) files, they don't compress well because they are already compressed. If you can make due with downgrading, figure out what format has the best tradeoffs for what you want to accomplish and then see if there is *reasonable* way to do it on mobile. It's been years since I researched both of these topics to save space on my home server, so I can't provide much more detail than this off the top of my head.